# Plotting of Network Topology graph based on json input

Tags: d3.js, highcharts, data-visualization, topology, noflo

I want to draw network topology graph with Highchart or any other js library by proving json data as input . While going through the example  at http://www.highcharts.com/demo/renderer for Topology plot requirement ,  I found that it is  static and doesn't have any example with fixed json format to render topology dynamically on basis of topology xml .

seeking help to plot Logical Topology/network topologies based on various json /xml.

Comment: In general, what kind of information your json keeps?

Comment: json will have parent child node relationship,on basis of which topology will be plotted. Below is an example of what I want to draw:    https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0BxIZT77zFtlFQk93RkUtVWRsbnM&usp=sharing

Comment: Ok so you need parse your json to have any elements, then use renderer with defined elemets position (in pixels) and add each of them.

Comment: That's okay but my xml/json could have diffrent number of nodes/relationship/attribute.looking for a solution which can plot automatically instead of manual drawing. with every call on server different type of json will be fetched

Comment: Unforunatley highcharts cannot predict all aspesct, you need to have any schema of chart, then render.

Answer (score 5):

Check out [netjsongraph.js](https://github.com/interop-dev/netjsongraph.js).

See the [netjsongraph demo example](https://nodeshot.org/netjsongraph/examples/index.html).

It's based on D3 and it uses the [NetJSON](http://netjson.org) format, which is specifically designed for networking software.

I hope it helps.

Comment: thanks for replying but Instead of pre-plotted diagram I want to create document on the flow. here is an example what I actually need http://app.flowhub.io/#example/6699161  . The only difference is in :my case objects(node here) will be fetched from DB and user should be able to draw digram by selecting these objects from the list of objects.