# How to pretty topology graph

Tags: javascript, d3.js, topology, topological-sort

I have drawn a topology graph using `javascript`, but the problem is how to pretty the graph display.
I even use force-directed data to random my nodes position,
 but when the nodes get more,  the graph looks bad
[image]
How can it be like below: 
[image]

How can I do ? Could someone tell me what I can looking for ?

Comment: The first step is usually provide the same dataset, or network topology, and see whether the layout produces similar results. In your case you have two different topologies in the two pictures.

Comment: Related answer s/o http://stackoverflow.com/a/33199117/1494833

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See [working jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/meetamit/fhez7vgm/8/)

```
var root = { name: "root" };
var hosts = [
  { name: "host1", type: "host" },
  { name: "host2", type: "host" },
  { name: "host3", type: "host" }
];

var nodes = [root].concat(hosts);
var links = hosts.map(function(host) {
  return { source: root, target: host }
});

hosts.forEach(function(host) {
  var hostNum = host.name.substr(4);
  for(var i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
    var vm = {
      name: "vm-" + hostNum + "-" + i,
      type: 'vm'
    }
    nodes.push(vm);
    links.push({
      source: host,
      target: vm
    })
  }
});

var force = d3.layout.force()
  .size([window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight])
  .nodes(nodes)
  .links(links)
  .charge(-1500)
  .gravity(0.1)
  .on('tick', update)
  .start();

var svg = d3.select('body')
  .append('svg')
  .attr({
    width:  window.innerWidth,
    height: window.innerHeight
  })

var circles = svg.selectAll('circle')
  .data(force.nodes())
circles.enter()
  .append('circle')
  .attr({
    r: function(d) { return d.type == 'vm' ? 14 : 20; },
    fill: '#1661FE'
  });

var lines = svg.selectAll('line')
  .data(force.links())
lines.enter()
  .append('line')
  .attr({
    fill: 'none',
    stroke: '#1661FE',
    'stroke-width': 3
  });

var texts = svg.selectAll('text')
  .data(force.nodes())
texts.enter()
  .append('text')
  .text(function(d) { return d.name; })
  .attr({
    fill: 'white',
    'text-anchor': 'middle',
    dy: '30'
  })
  .style({
    'font-family': "Verdana, Helvetica, Sans-Serif",
    'font-size': 12
  });

function update() {
  circles.attr({
    cx: function(d) { return d.x; },
    cy: function(d) { return d.y; }
  });

  texts.attr({
    x: function(d) { return d.x; },
    y: function(d) { return d.y; }
  })

  lines.attr({
    x1: function(d) { return d.source.x},
    y1: function(d) { return d.source.y},
    x2: function(d) { return d.target.x},
    y2: function(d) { return d.target.y},
  })
}
```

Comment: That's *very* pretty

Comment: hei, sorry for not reply few days. I'm going to try your demo, thank you very much